# happened in the past, but used a simple present tense

Tags: tense

[Katie Brennan speaks for the first time publicly. ‘My pleas went unanswered' by Murphy administration](https://www.nj.com/politics/2018/12/katie-brennan-speaks-for-the-first-time-publicly-my-voice-went-unheard-by-murphy-administration.html)

> Brennan recounted the days, weeks and months after she **says** she was
>   raped by Albert J. Alvarez, who resigned in October as chief of staff
>   to the New Jersey Schools Development Authority.

I think she "says" happened in the past, and the main tense is also in past tense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be in the past if it were an action which has stopped.  The fact that present is used implies that she has never actually *stopped* saying it.

In other words, she was saying it then, and she's saying it now.

Comment: Then, the next question. " weeks and months after she says she was raped " means the weeks ... after she was raped, or the weeks ... after the first time she says she was raped to the public?

Comment: "before"? I think it's "after"